# Listing ScalikeJDBC results returning only one result

Tags: scala, scalikejdbc

I am attempting to retrieve a list of user IDs from a database in Scala using ScalikeJDBC.  My issue is that the query, when I run it in a database tool, returns many rows.  However, when I attempt to retrieve this data as a list in Scala, it contains only one element.  Is there something I am missing?

```
val ids = List(1,2,3,4)
val statement =
  sql"""
      SELECT
       |  id
       |from users
       |where id in (${ids mkString ","})
       ;
    """.stripMargin
NamedDB('aurora) readOnly { implicit session =>
  val list:List[Int] = statement.map(rs => rs.int("id")).list.apply()
  //prints "list size: 1"
  println(s"list size: ${list.size}")
}
```

ScalikeJDBC docs [here](http://scalikejdbc.org/documentation/operations.html).

Comment: So you're executing `SELECT id FROM users WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4);` in your DB tool and seeing multiple results? Your code look correct, have you double checked things such as your definitely using same database connection?

Comment: Also, if your list only contains 1 value, what is it?

Comment: @timothyclifford, very suspiciously it selects only the first id of the list

Comment: Is there a reason you're using all the `|` in your select statement?

Comment: @timothyclifford those characters are for pretty formatting and are removed by stripMargin().  I have run this without those characters and the result is the same.

Comment: Brian, to re-state what Timothy asked in the first comment, what happens if you remove the `where` clause altogether? Do you still get only one record? Which one? In other words, do you really have more than 1 record in the subset of `id in (1,2,3,4)` in your DB?